# XML: DeepEquals fails on downloaded vs saved downloaded documents?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm using this to compare the documents

```
if (XNode.DeepEquals(cachedDocument, document))
```

Let's do a little science here. I download my XML documents from an API, I'm basically checking the 2 documents to ensure the latest doesn't have any changed. Basically ensuring that its not had any changes since I last cached the API xml file.

```
XDocument document = null;

if (useCachedDocuments && File.Exists(postCacheDirectory + "/photos/page " + (i + 1) + ".xml"))
{
    document = XDocument.Parse(postCacheDirectory + "/photos/page " + (i + 1) + ".xml");
}
else
{
    document = XDocument.Load(GetApiLink(pageAddress, i * 50, true));
}

if (i == 1 && File.Exists(postCacheDirectory + "/photos/page 1.xml"))
{
    var cachedDocument = XDocument.Load(postCacheDirectory + "/photos/page 1.xml");

    if (XNode.DeepEquals(cachedDocument, document))
    {
        Logger.Warn("We can start to use cached documents now, wayyyy faster :D");
        useCachedDocuments = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.Warn("Sorry, no cache avalible here...");
    }
}
```

The cached document is the exact same as I cached, I literally download it and save it. I know for certain theres been no changes yet `DeepEquals` fails??

Comment: Have you tried saving the returned object from the API, then using a diff tool like codecompare or kdiff against the one that you manually downloaded?

Comment: Are you loading the entire documents? GetApiLink(pageAddress, i * 50, true)